# VBScript Windows autologin script

Tags: windows, vbscript, autologin

I'm trying to write a VBScript to automatically login to Windows by using the registry and InputBox / Msgbox. I'm new to VBScript so I don't really know anything, but I was thinking about something like this:

```
Set WshSehll = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windwos NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultUserName", "Myusername", "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windwos NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultPassword", "Mypassword" "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windwos NT\Current Version\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon", "1", "REG_SZ"

Dim sInput
sInput = InputBox "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windwos NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultUserName", "Myusername" ("Username: ")
sInput = InputBox "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windwos NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultPassword", "Mypassword" ("Password: ")
```

My idea was to open a window in which you can enter the username and password, press OK or Cancel. Pretty simple, but I haven't found a way to combine the values of the registry keys with the input fields. Some tips or any kind of help are appreciated.

Comment: You have it backwards. Capture the value from your `InputBox()` in variables `user` and `pwd` for example then use them to populate the `RegWrite()` call replacing `"Myusername"` with `user` and `"Mypassword"` with pwd.

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to first capture the values from the `InputBox()` calls before you can update the registry, try something like this;

```
Dim user, pwd
Dim wsh: Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Collect input.
user = InputBox("Username: ", "Enter Username")
pwd = InputBox("Password: ", "Enter Password")

'Assess whether registry should be updated.
If Len(user) > 0 Then
    Call wsh.RegWrite("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultUserName", user, "REG_SZ")
End If
If Len(pwd) > 0 Then
    Call wsh.RegWrite("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultPassword", pwd, "REG_SZ")
End If

Call wsh.RegWrite("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon", Abs((Len(user) > 0 And Len(password) > 0)), "REG_SZ")
```

<sup>**Also corrected some typos in the registry path.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you! There is an error on line 10 where the script calls the registry key. You get the error when the registry key doesn't exist (also checked myself). I'll try to find a way to add / update the keys in the script.

Comment: @user12398266 there will be, this isn't a bullet-proof solution I've simply re-ordered your code and added some basic checks. I'll leave the error handling to you.

Comment: I searched for a way to add/update keys and added this to the code:

`Dim ObjShell`
`Dim ShellObject`
`Set ObjShell = ShellObject.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\DefaultUserName")`
`If ObjShell = "" then`
`ShellObject.Popup "doesn't exist, will be added","4",""`
`ShellObject.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\"`
`else`
`ShellObject.Popup "exists","3",""`
`end if`

I get an error saying that a value has been expected at Set ObjShell, but I can't really seem to solve this.

Comment: Well, I'll keep trying then. Thanks anyway!